# If two vectors are perpendicular, the triangles are similar.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm working through Ted Shifrin Linear algebra and when introducing the dot product he motivates it by saying that if P and Q are two points in the plane and the angle $\angle POQ$ is a right angle then the triangles $\triangle OAP$ and $\triangle OBQ$ are similar where A is the projection of $\vec{OP}$ along the x-axis and B is the projection of $\vec{OQ}$ along the y-axis (see image).
[image]

Now, I'm not that good in geometry so i got little bit lost in this part. How would one prove that the triangles are similar, which theorems/postulates are used?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use that angle POB is complementry to both your desired equal angles.

Comment: The angle of rotation is the same so the sine and cosine are the same. Therefore, the ratio of one vector's length to the other is the same when you multiply by the sine and cosine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As given in question, ∠ POQ = 90.

Thus ∠POB and ∠BOQ are complementary to each other,
i.e.
∠POB + ∠BOQ =90

Also, OA ⊥ OB,

Thus, ∠BOP + ∠ AOP = 90

Now, comparing both,

We can prove, ∠BOQ = ∠AOP

Also, ∠OBQ = ∠OAP = 90

As two angles are equal, we can apply AA similarity in the two triangles.
Thus, they are similar.